# TextToSpeech dont talk out of onTouch method android development

Tags: android

Well I'm trying to use `texttospeech` when I'm creating an activity but only when I touch the view, and the method `onTouch` called its talk, here's the code:

> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_d);
>
>     tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
>     tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
>
>     tts.speak("Check Check", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
>
>     d = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.d_layout);
>     d.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
>         @Override
>         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
>             tts.speak("Check Check Check", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
>             return false;
>         }
>     });
>
>
> }
> ```

Only when I touch its say check check check, but when I start the activity it don't say check check, why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling `speak()` before the `TextToSpeech` object has been initialized. You need to listen for the `onInit()` call for the listener that is passed to the `TextToSpeech` constructor (see here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnInitListener.html).

The view touch is most likely happening late enough where the speech engine is already ready. More specifically, I suspect that the order that things are happening is as follows:

1. `tts = new TextToSpeech(this,this)`
2. `tts.speak("Check Check", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);` (this does not work)
3. (time passes)
4. `onInit()` gets called indicating that the `TextToSpeech` object is ready.
5. (time passes)
6. User touches the layout and `tts.speak("Check Check Check", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);` is called. (This works)

As you can see only the `speak()` calls that come after the `onInit()` call actually work.

Comment: how can i fix it? i tried to set the language in the onInit Method and its didnt work for me, what now?